# Skew-symmetric bicharacters on $A$ and $H^2(A,\mathbb{C}^{\times})$

Tags: abelian-groups, group-cohomology

Let $A$ be a finite abelian group. I have read that there is an isomorphism of abelian groups between the group $H^2(A;\mathbb{C}^{\times})$, and the group of skew-symmetric bicharacters on $A$, i.e. bilinear maps $b:A\times A\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ such that $b(x,x)=1$ for every $x\in A$. How does one prove this result?

In particular, is it true that this isomorphism is **not** induced by the canonical map: $$\{bicharacters\}\rightarrow H^2(A;\mathbb{C}^{\times})$$

Comment: First, you need to precise  the action of $A$ on $\mathbb{C}^\times$. Secondly, the statement you wrote is not reasonable in its current state. You need at least an equivalence relation on the set of skew-symmetric bicharacters (probably isomorphism).

Comment: I did not specify the action on $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ because it is the trivial action. I don't see what makes this statement unreasonable, could you please elaborate?

Comment: What is this canonical map that you claim? There is an obvious map in the *other* direction, sending a group cocycle to its skew, but I can't see how to construct a map the other way round.

Comment: @Kofi I think the author is referring to the natural map which sends a bicharacter (which is automatically a cocycle) to its cohomology class. It is true indeed that this map in general is not an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found in proposition 2.6 of this [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02803515) by D. Tambara.

Namely, let $X^2_a(A)$ denote the group of skew-symmetric bicharacters. There is a canonical map $Alt:Z^2(A;\mathbb{C}^{\times})\rightarrow X^2_a(A)$, given by $\gamma\mapsto \{(a,b)\mapsto \gamma(a,b)/\gamma(b,a)\}$. It is not hard to check that this map factors through $Alt:H^2(A;\mathbb{C}^{\times})\rightarrow X^2_a(A)$.

If $\gamma\in Z^2(A;\mathbb{C}^{\times})$ is such that $Alt(\gamma)=1$, then the central extension of $A$ by $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ specified by $\gamma$ is abelian. But $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is divisible, whence injective as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Thus, this extension is trivial, and $\gamma$ is a 2-coboundary.

Surjectivity can be checked by inspection.